# Login page does not succeed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a login page with user and password controls. When I click the login button the script checks the availability of user and password in the database table (register) with a stored procedure (LoginCheck), but when I enter the data it will never succeed, it always fails.

Below is the code script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlConnection conn = new        SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Mydatabase"].ConnectionString);
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("LoginCheck", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User", TextUsr.Text.Trim().ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextPass.Text.Trim().ToString());
          adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
          adp.Fill(dt);
          cmd.Dispose();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Login Successfully" + dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            clearcontrols();
        }
        else
        {
              lblStatus.Text = "Wrong username of password "+dt.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblStatus.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
      //  reader.Close();
        dt.Clear();
        dt.Dispose();
        adp.Dispose();
        conn.Close();

    }


}
private void clearcontrols()
{
    TextUsr.Text = "";
    TextPass.Text = "";
}
}
```

Below is the stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE LoginCheck

@User nvarchar(50),
@Password nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

Select * from Register where User=@User and Password=@Password
END
```

Comment: First thing to check is if the username/password work on their own - execute the stored procedure and see what happens.

Comment: Chances are the passwords don't match because you're trying to match what the user typed in to a hashed value in the database.

Comment: Check the inputs by putting a break point, so you'll know what the textbox returns, and then check in your database if it really matches letters for letters, one good checkup would be to do the other way around, try to put the first combination of login/password in your textboxs

Comment: I hope you're not storing passwords as clear text in your database, especially if this is a production system....

Comment: Is there an error?  Or does the call to the stored proc just return zero rows?

Answer (score 0):

I found what cause the login fail, it was the column name user in the table register, it conflicts with system user name in the framework, I changed to Username and is now working fine.